# Make a fit surface transparent in a 3D logloglog plot...transparence with FaceAlpha is not working

Tags: matlab

I have a log log log 3D plot in which I fit some data with a surface. I am driving crazy to provide some transparence to the surface in order to see my data underneath.. Here is a minimal example where I generate some random date and I do the power law fit, that in a log scale becomes a plane. Any suggestion? I basically want a transparent gray surface. I read the manual, using FaceAlpha but not working. Thanks. A.

```
%generate a vector of X and Y variables
[Log10X,Log10Y] = meshgrid(1.1:0.1:2);
Log10X = reshape(Log10X,100,1);
Log10Y = reshape(Log10Y,100,1);
%Specity Z as a function of X and Y (i.e. it lays on a plane)
A=0.3; B=0.4;
Log10Z =A*Log10X + B*Log10Y;
%%Add in a noise vector
noise =0.02*randn(100,1);
Log10Z= Log10Z + noise;
%compute "original" X,Y,Z
X = 10.^Log10X;
Y = 10.^Log10Y;
Z = 10.^Log10Z;
figure
scatter3(X,Y,Z, 'filled')
hold on
f = fittype( @(a, b, c, x, y) a*x.^b.*y.^c, 'independent', {'x', 'y'}, 'dependent', 'z');
[sf,gof] = fit( [X, Y],Z,f,'startpoint', [0.9 0.3 0.4] ) %, 'Robust', 'LAR'
XLIM = [min(X) max(X) ]
YLIM = [min(Y) max(Y) ]
HANDLEsur = plot(sf,'XLim',XLIM,'YLim',YLIM )
set(gca,'xscale','log','yscale','log','zscale','log')
xlim(XLIM)
ylim(YLIM)
set(HANDLEsur,'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor',[0.5 0.5 0.5],'FaceAlpha',0.3)
```

EDIT:
trying to do the workaround suggested, but it looks complicated to do that for a 3d plot, for a 2D plot you can do this, but it does not work for 3D:

```
%replace linear XTickLabel with log XTickLabel
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',[])     %# suppress current x-labels 
xt = get(gca, 'XTick');
yl = get(gca, 'YLim');
str = cellstr( num2str(xt(:),'10^{%d}') );      %# format x-ticks as 10^{xx}


hTxt = text(xt, yl(ones(size(xt))), str, ...   %# create text at same locations
  'Interpreter','tex', ...                     %# specify tex interpreter
  'VerticalAlignment','top', ...               %# v-align to be underneath
  'HorizontalAlignment','center');             %# h-aligh to be centered
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have transparency with log axes: unfortunately the only renderer that supports transparency in MATLAB is OpengGL, but it does not support log axes!

More info in [Renderer](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html#Renderer).

A workaround is to log transform your data, plot on linear axes and set the ticklabels manually.

Comment: Thanks good to know. I have hard time to do that for a 3D plot. Xticklabel does not accept latex interpreter...

Comment: You can use a workaround for ticklabels [FEX: Format Tick Labels](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15986), but how is this related with log scaling or transparency?

Comment: Actually, this one should support 3D text labelling: [FEX: tick2text()](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16003)

Comment: its related, because I want to have 10^0, 10^1,10^2... on the axis, with the exponent as an upperscript and I was using 10^{xx} in the string vector str  but latex is not allowed for Xticklabel ...I tried to use that tick2text() but I could not make it work...are u sure it can do what im looking for?thanks

Comment: `axis([0,100,0,100,0,100]);
tick2text(gca,'axis','xyz', 'convert', true,'zformat',@(x) sprintf('%d^{10}',x));`

Comment: Thanks. we are getting closer, the actual call is tick2text(gca,'axis','xyz', 'convert', true,'xformat',@(x) sprintf('10^{%d}',x),'yformat',@(x) sprintf('10^{%d}',x),'zformat',@(x) sprintf('10^{%d}',x))
. And I can change their size with: hx = getappdata(gca, 'XTickText');set(hx,  'fontsize', 18);. But now 2 problems arise: the zlabel overlaps my z ticks. And size of xlabel,ylabel and zlabel becomes smaller and does not respond anymore to set(gca,'FontSize',20). Any idea?

Comment: @Alberto You are going out of topic. I answered your question and went beyond. Please, consider opening a new question which reproduces the issue. As a side note `h = zlabel('something'); set(h, 'FontSize',20);`

Comment: I dont think I am going out of topic. I saw a lot of people around the web driving crazy to do transparence an log-log in 3D. And we did not find a well working solution yet. If we write in your answer a working snippet I m pretty sure your answer would get 100 thumb ups, that would be a reference workaround. And we are close but not there yet with having a well-working 3D logloglog plot with transparency enabled.

Comment: anyways I solved the overlapping problem by doing set(zlab,'Position',get(zlab,'Position') - [1 0 0]). Thanks for helping.

Comment: It's not about the thumbs up, it's about expectations. You state "I am driving crazy to provide some transparence to the surface... Any suggestion?" Well, you can't with a log plots. Then you kept asking incremental question about formatting a plot which I see as disconnected from the original question. My suggestion, re-edit your initial question, add a minimal working example that does not require Curve Fitting TB (I don't have it) and clearly state "what would be a state of the art workaround?". Otherwise, no other than me will read these lengthy comments.